# can not display value of HashMap in JSTL in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I don't understand why value of map is not displayed in JSP.

Controller side:

```
.....
List<String> codes=new ArryList<String>();
codes.add("DATA_BASE");
codes.add("CSV_FILE");
codes.add("WEB_SERVICE");
model.addAttribute("codes",codes);
.....
Map<String,String> labelsMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
labelsMap.put("DATA_BASE","Data base");
labelsMap.put("CSV_FILE","CSV file");
labelsMap.put("WEB_SERVICE","Web service");
model.addAttribute("labelsMap",labelsMap);
....
```

View side:

```
<c:forEach var="code" items="${codes}" >
code is: <c:out value="${code}">
value is: <c:out value="${labelsMap[code]}">
</c:forEach>
```

Result:

```
code is: DATA_BASE
value is: 

code is: CSV_FILE
value is: 

code is: WEB_SERVICE
value is:
```

Values of `labelsMap` are not displayed.

Comment: value is: <c:out value="${labelsMap['${code}']}">   maybe sounds better?

Answer (score 1):

how about this? what expression language you are using? EL or OGNL?

```
<c:out value="${labelsMap["${code}"]}">
```